# magento coupon code not apply on grandtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes, totals

I have issue/confusion.

While I try to add a coupon code to my Magento 1 store at that time the Grand total (Including Tax) not changing.

**Coupon information**

> 1. Code: demo123
> 2. Condition: for all products
> 3. Action: 5% of products prices.

**Issue/Confusion**

[image]

While you check in image.

```
Total = 12.99
And discount = -0.65
```

So grand total(Include Tax) must be **12.34** but as you see in the image it is showing me wrong.

Tax = 21%

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please check my answer. Maybe that'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to changes some settings from your Magento admin.

> Goto: Admin > System > Cofiguration > Sales > Tax > (And Change Setting as per following Screeshot)

[image]

Set Apply Customer Tax = Before Discount and save config and clean your cache and check.

Good Luck!!

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: @Nirav-Joshi Please try with this and let me know it's this working for you or not?

Comment: No it is not worked..